How did Ataru Mizorogi not realize what his students were doing?
How did the Class Black's sensei, Ataru Mizorogi, not catch on to what everyone was up to? I mean, there was a pattern to when everyone left. Hitsugi and Chitaru killed each other, students began to leave at random times, and there were fights in the hallway!  And when he reads off attendance, there are missing kids, so how does he not realize this? I mean, how blind is this dude? Also, in the Special, did he not hear what Nio was saying, not find a weapon on the island, and why was he there? I guess I am just wondering why the show made him so blind.

